# Create distinct values in array - not yielding expected results

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make an array that has different values in its cells, but for some reason it has repeating values.  Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
package oefarray;

public class OefArray {

    int[] getallenArray,differentArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OefArray arr = new OefArray();
        arr.differentArray(10,10);

    }

    public void differentArray(int n, int max) {
        differentArray= new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < differentArray.length; i++) {
            int value = (int) (Math.random() * max);
            differentArray[i]= value;
            for (int p: differentArray){
                while (value == p){
                    value = (int) (Math.random() * max);
                }
            }
            differentArray[i]= value;
            System.out.println(differentArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All your code will do, is make sure the value for `value` is different than the last value in `differentArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking whether the new generated value exists anywhere in the array, only that its value doesn't equal the current value you're examining.

```
differentArray= new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < differentArray.length; i++) {
    int value = 0;
    while(true){
        value = (int)(Math.random()*max);
        boolean found = false;
        for(int p: differentArray){
            if(p==value){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) break;
    }
    differentArray[i] = value;
}
```

Here's an alternative to arshajii's solution which doesn't require a direct reference to `ArrayList`. As he pointed out, this is no more efficient than his solution. Just another way of writing it if you're not comfortable with Lists yet.

```
int[] nums = new int[max];
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    nums[i] = i;
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(nums));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    differentArray[i] = nums.get(i);
```

Comment: Yea but the array has size `n` not size `max`. That's why I used a list in the first place.

Comment: True, I apologize, I was mistaken. Your solution is fine. Edited answer. You don't need a list directly.

Answer (score 0):

For a futuristic approach to this using Java 8, using `IntStream.generate` can produce some very terse results.  This likely performs in the same performance window as the previous answer, so I make no assertion that this is more *efficient*.  It is, however, more expressive.

```
public int[] differentArray(int length, int maxValue) {
    if(length > maxValue) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of possible unique values is smaller than available number of slots for them.");
    }
    final Random random = new Random();
    return IntStream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(maxValue))
                    .distinct()
                    .limit(length)
                    .toArray();
}
```